# Mapping the array element with other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have two arrays

```
array1 = [{id:"1",title:"Writing"},{id:"2",title:"Singing"},{id:"3",title:"Dance"}];

array2 = [{tags: "1",title: "USA",type: "text"},
{tags: "1,2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"},
{tags: "2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"}];
```

I have to map the `id` of the array1 to `tags` of the array2 and display the corresponding title from the array1.

The new array2 should look like,

```
array2=[{tags:"Writing",title:"USA", type:"text"},
{tags: "Writing,Singing,Dance",title: "Japan",type: "image"},
{tags: "Singing,Dance",title: "Japan",type: "image"}];
```

I did this to get the array1 mapping and got stuck after that.

```
var newtags= (array1).map(obj=>{
var rObj={};
rObj[obj.id]=obj.title;
return rObj;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here's a solution

I'm using .map, .reduce and .replace to join array1 and array2 together.

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        id: "1",
        title: "Writing"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        title: "Singing"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        title: "Dance"
    }
]

const array2 = [
    {
        tags: "1",
        title: "USA",
        type: "text"
    },
    {
        tags: "1,2,3",
        title: "Japan",
        type: "image"
    },
    {
        tags: "2,3",
        title: "Japan",
        type: "image"
    }
]

const array3 = 
  array2.map(item => ({ 
    ...item,
    tags: array1.reduce((tags, {id, title}) => tags.replace(id, title), item.tags),
  }))
  
console.log(array3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the operation?

Comment: If there are ids greater than 10, it will replace `1` and it will become `Writing0`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mapping object with each `id` as key and `title` as value using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Then `map` over `array2` and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) each `tags` to get the new tags

```js
const array1=[{id:"1",title:"Writing"},{id:"2",title:"Singing"},{id:"3",title:"Dance"}],
      array2=[{tags:"1",title:"USA",type:"text"},{tags:"1,2,3",title:"Japan",type:"image"},{tags:"2,3",title:"Japan",type:"image"}]

const map = array1.reduce((r, { id, title }) => ({ ...r, [id]: title }), {});

const output = array2.map(({ tags, ...rest }) => {
  const newTags = tags.split(',').map(id => map[id]).join(',')
  return { tags: newTags, ...rest }
})

console.log(output)
```

You could also get the mapping object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```
const map = Object.fromEntries(array1.map(({ id, title }) => [id, title]));
```

Then use the regex `/\d+(?=,|$)/` to match the numbers and replace them with their respective `title`s

```js
const array1=[{id:"1",title:"Writing"},{id:"2",title:"Singing"},{id:"3",title:"Dance"}],
      array2=[{tags:"1",title:"USA",type:"text"},{tags:"1,2,3",title:"Japan",type:"image"},{tags:"2,3",title:"Japan",type:"image"}]

const map = Object.fromEntries(array1.map(({ id, title }) => [id, title]));

const output = array2.map(({ tags, ...rest }) => {
  const newTags = tags.replace(/\d+(?=,|$)/g, n => map[n])
  return { tags: newTags, ...rest }
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

- Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert `array1` into an `object` with `id` as **key** and `title` as **value** (**Step 1**)
- Iterate over `array2` using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) to update its tags property

  - To update `tags` property first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it by `,` to convert into an `array`
  - [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each value in `array` to its corresponding value in `Object` created in **step 1**
  - [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) back the array with `,` and assign back to `tags`

```js
let array1 = [{id:"1",title:"Writing"},{id:"2",title:"Singing"},{id:"3",title:"Dance"}];
let array2 = [{tags: "1",title: "USA",type: "text"},{tags: "1,2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"},{tags: "2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"}];

let obj = array1.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.id] : c.title}), {});
array2.forEach(o => o.tags = o.tags.split(",").map(v => obj[v]).join(","));

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, split tags and filter tags in array1 first.

```
var newtags= (array2).map(obj=>{
   let tags = obj.tags.split(",");
   let titles = array1.filter(c=>tags.includes(c.id)).map(c=>c.title);
   obj.tags = titles.join();
   return obj;
});
```

```js
array1 = [{id:"1",title:"Writing"},{id:"2",title:"Singing"},{id:"3",title:"Dance"}];

array2 = [{tags: "1",title: "USA",type: "text"},
{tags: "1,2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"},
{tags: "2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"}];

var newtags= (array2).map(obj=>{
let tags = obj.tags.split(",");
let titles = array1.filter(c=>tags.includes(c.id)).map(c=>c.title);
obj.tags = titles.join();
return obj;
});
console.log(newtags);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of looping array1 and replacing array2 tags with title

1. Loop Array1 using forEach
2. Replace array2 tags with each array1 title using array id

```js
array1 = [{id:"1",title:"Writing"},{id:"2",title:"Singing"},{id:"3",title:"Dance"}];

array2 = [{tags: "1",title: "USA",type: "text"},
{tags: "1,2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"},
{tags: "2,3",title: "Japan",type: "image"}];



array1.forEach(v =>{
const re = new RegExp(v.id, "g");
array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array2).replace(re, v.title))
})

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider breaking this down into several reusable functions.  Of course it might be premature abstraction, but I've seen variants of this questions like often enough here that it makes sense to me to look toward the fundamentals.

We want to be able to look up the values in a list stored as an array with what might be arbitrary field names.  So we use a function `makeDictionary` that takes both the field names and the array and returns an object that maps them, such as {'1': 'Writing', '2': 'Singing',...}`.

Then we can use `fillField` supplying a dictionary, a field name, and an object, and replace that field with the result of looking up the tags in the dictionary.  This is a little more specific to the problem, mostly because the comma-separated string format for your tags is a little more cumbersome than it might be if it were an array.

With these, `useTags` is simple to write, and it is the first function here focused directly on your needs.  It combines the above, supplying the field names `id` and `title` for the dictionary and `tags` for your main objects.

This is what it looks like combined:

```js
const makeDictionary = (keyName, valName) => (arr) => 
  arr .reduce 
    ( (a, {[keyName]: k, [valName]: v}) => ({...a, [k]: v}) 
    , {} 
    )

const fillField = (field, dict) => ({[field]: f, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  [field]: f .split (/,\s*/) .map (t => dict[t]) .join (', ')
})


const useTags = (tags, dict = makeDictionary ('id', 'title') (tags) ) =>
  (objs) => objs .map ( fillField ('tags', dict) )


const tags = [{id: "1", title: "Writing"}, {id: "2", title: "Singing"}, {id: "3", title: "Dance"}];

const updateTags = useTags (tags) 

const items = [{tags: "1", title: "USA", type: "text"}, {tags: "1, 2, 3", title: "Japan", type: "image"}, {tags: "2, 3", title: "Japan", type: "image"}];

console .log (
  updateTags (items)
)
```

**Note** that I took a little liberty with the `tags: "2,3"` and `tags: "Singing,Dance"` formats, adding a little white space.  It's trivial to take this out.  But even better, if possible, would be to change this to use arrays for your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a real [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map the values to the new objects.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: "1", title: "Writing" }, { id: "2", title: "Singing" }, { id: "3", title: "Dance" }],
    array2 = [{ tags: "1", title: "USA", type: "text" }, { tags: "1,2,3", title: "Japan", type: "image" }, { tags: "2,3", title: "Japan", type: "image" }],
    tags = array1.reduce((m, { id, title }) => m.set(id, title), new Map),
    result = array2.map(o => ({ ...o, tags: o.tags.split(',').map(Map.prototype.get, tags).join() }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```